# Getting error when attempting to add items into the database

Tags: python, django

So, I am actively trying to create categories with subcategories. My current app is `listings`, and the idea is to create a `ManyToManyField` inside my `Listing` models. Here is my code inside `models.py`.

```
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

class Blist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Business Name', max_length=250)
    address = models.CharField('Address', max_length=300)
    city = models.CharField('City', max_length=100)
    zip_code = models.CharField('Zip Code', max_length=10)
    phone_number = models.CharField('Phone Number', max_length=20)
    web = models.URLField('Website')

    def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

But when I go into the `shell` to add items into the category, I'm getting errors:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column listings_category.name does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "listings_category"."id", "listings_category"."name",...
```

Once finished, I ran `makemigrations` and `migrate`, but I realize it is not creating the tables in my database. I'm using Postgresql.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe you missed on running make migrations and migrate commands

Comment: I ran both. I have realized that it is not creating the tables.

Comment: use python manage.py migrate appname 0001 . this (0001) is your migration file name. which is start with 0001,0002 . specify which migration you wanna run .

Comment: Even running the command with the specific number (0001) it is not pushing the changes to the database.

Comment: @AggregateScore please post your migration file.